# Why is New Relic still saying my application is susceptible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, security, newrelic

I upgraded a Rails application from 3.2.16 to 3.2.22.2 in a deploy yesterday afternoon (about 13 hours ago), but New Relic still says

> Our latest report on this application shows the following outdated
>   frameworks which may be susceptible to security attacks:
>
> rails (3.2.16)
>
> See rails for up to date information on specific vulnerabilities. Was
>   this notification useful or not?

Does it take a while for New Relic to get informed about what version of Rails is being used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your application running on more than one server? If so, were the other servers updated as well? The message will persist if any server is running the older version.